# string append in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

my ajax response is a string array like this `{"excount":2 "ex1":{"status":1}"ex2":{"status":2}}`
i need to iterate this inside loop and alert in java script
my code shown below

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: getContextPath()+"/cons/trackConsOrders",
            data: {}, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(resdata) {
                      count = Object.keys(resdata).length;
                      $("#id-dynamic-order-track").empty();



                      for(i=0;i<count;i++){

                          for(j=0;j<resdata[i].excount;j++){
                            alert(resdata[i].ex"+j+".status);
                           }
                     }
```

alert is not working because of wrong syntax...i need to append j value after ex. Is it possible?.please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: The string you show is not valid JSON, but you've told jQuery to expect JSON. You need to fix the server-side code to return valid JSON.

Comment: `resdata[i].ex"+j+".status` is not valid JavaScript either.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `for in` to iterate the js object, like:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}

// Output:
// "obj.a = 1"
// "obj.b = 2"
// "obj.c = 3"
```

Comment: What 's the problem, the question is: iterate the value of the map object and alert the value. That is what my answer is doing. Is there any problem?